# Rotate one row in matrix of nodes (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, tikz-matrix

I am trying to rotate one row of a matrix of nodes. Is it possible?

**MWE (rotation does not work):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes={circle,draw},
row 1/.style={align=left,rotate=90}]
{
t & &  \\
y & & v \\
h & g & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `transform shape` to rotate the contents of a `node`. Further, you may wish to add `anchor=center`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes={circle,draw,text depth=0.5ex,text height=1.5ex},
row 1/.style={nodes={align=left,rotate=90,anchor=center,transform shape}}]
{
t & &  \\
y & & v \\
h & g & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Further, it is better to use `text width` so that all nodes align. Finally as mentioned by percusse apply the `rotate` operation only on nodes by

```
row 1/.style={nodes={align=left,rotate=90,anchor=center,transform shape}}
```

Comment: Use `row 1/.style={nodes={align=left,rotate=90}}` syntax instead otherwise bad things will happen.